# Error messages on page with the <h:messages> in JSF

Tags: java, jsf, jsf-2, message

I'm creating simple example on JSF. It's small Login application. My problem is duplicate error messages on my page:

[image: my screen]

I have two `h:message`(for username and password) tags and one `h:messages`(global messages) on my page:

```
<h:form id="loginForm">

   <h:panelGrid columns="3">

       <h:outputText value="Username" />
       <h:inputText id="username" value="#{loginBean.username}" 
                  required="true" requiredMessage="Please enter your username" />
       <h:message for="username" errorClass="errorMessage" /> <!-- Message for username -->

       <h:outputText value="Password" />
       <h:inputSecret id="password" value="#{loginBean.password}" 
                  required="true" requiredMessage="Please enter your password" />
       <h:message for="password" errorClass="errorMessage" /> <!-- Message for password -->


       <h:commandButton value="Login" action="#{loginBean.login}" />

   </h:panelGrid>

   <h:messages styleClass="errorMessage" /> <!-- Global messages -->


</h:form>
```

Action method `login()` in my backing bean:

```
public String login() {
    FacesContext facesContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
    if ("admin".equals(username) && "pass".equals(password)) {
        return "success";
    } else {
        facesContext.addMessage("loginForm", new FacesMessage("Username or password is incorrect"));
        return null;
    }
}
```

I want to display **message about empty username or password only next to these fields**, not under my button in global messages. And I want to print my error **message from my action method in global messages** if password or username is incorrect. How can I resolve this?

I tried to use the attribute `globalOnly`:

```
<h:messages styleClass="errorMessage" globalOnly="true" /> <!-- Global messages -->
```

but it isn't completely solved my problem, because global messages aren't displayed at all in this case.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The `globalOnly` switch should work if you add your messages correctly in your backing bean. The client-id must be `null` in `FacesContext.addMessage(...)`:

```
FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, new FacesMessage(message));
```